# How to set checkout strategy in libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

I 'm trying to pull from a repo with libgit2.

My steps are these:

I use git_remote_fetch to down remote origin data and the return OK.

after I use git_merge API.

The question is when I just use **git_index_remove_bypath** deleted a file 'aa.txt' in local branch 'master', But not commit it. At the same times I Merge remote branch('origin/master') head. the remote head just modify 'bb.txt'.  But when I use **git_merge** it return error code '-13'. the error info is "1 uncommitted change would be overwritten by merge". I just deleted a file in my local branch.

But I can successed to execute in Git command line 'git pull'.

so, I suspect that my strategy is wrong when I execute Checkout. How to avoid this error？

Answer (score 1):

> I just deleted a file in my local branch.

If you only called `git_index_remove_bypath`, and you did not *commit* that change, then you have not deleted a file in your local branch.  You have an uncommitted change.

That's why you're getting this error:

> 1 uncommitted change would be overwritten by merge

Commit the change, then do the merge.  Or do the merge, then remove the file.  But doing the merge in the state you're in is not possible because it would remove uncommitted changes.

Comment: @Thomson, Thank you for your answer, it is very useful for me

Comment: @Thomson, Two users modify the same area of the same file, libgit2 will report content conflicts. this is OK. But I set a notify_cb in my git_checkout_options, and set notify_flags to include GIT_CHECKOUT_NOTIFY_CONFLICT. As result git_merge just return error code,No output conflict files name. How to get the conflict files name from notify callback, when merge failed?